# Xamarin.Essentials Share drawable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, share, xamarin.essentials

I'm trying to share a local image loacted in my Resources/Drawables folder in Android.
I'm using Xamarin and the Xamarin.Essentials plugin.
So there is this function:

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
Title = Title,
File = new ShareFile(file)
});
```

So for the File I need the Path to the File from the Drawable Folder.
I have tried so much variations.
For example:

```
var file = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Drawable.image).Path;
```

But I always get an error, that the file is not found.
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Resources don't have file paths.  You would need to copy it from Resources to a file folder

Comment: Can I Do this without additional permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Because Resources don't have file paths, as @Jason said I saved the image in another accesible file.
So I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works for me:

```
        Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.image, null);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;
        byte[] imgByteArray;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            imgByteArray = stream.ToArray();
        }

        var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "share.png");
        File.WriteAllBytes(file, imgByteArray);
        await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
        {
            Title = "Share",
            File = new ShareFile(file)
        });
```